# Putting a space after period using C

Tags: c

I have an assignment like
the codes must capitilize the first letter after period and put a space.
I wrote a function like that which capitalize the first letter after period.

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        continue;
    }
    if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
    {
        ++i;
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
            str[i] = str[i] + 32;
    }
}
```

But I couldn't do the putting space part can someone help me pls

Comment: Use `islower`, `isupper`,  `tolower`, and `toupper`

Comment: You need to clarify the question.  Do you need to store this data in a buffer, or are you simply writing it out to a stream?  The solutions for each are very different.

Answer (score 2):

Adding spaces in your string means you're final string will contain more characters than the original one.
Thus you'll need to allocate memory, using [malloc](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

What you can do is:

- Get the period count in your string
- Deduce the number of spaces you'll have to add
- Allocate a new string that is `strlen(old_string) + space_count + 1` long
- Finally iterate through your old string, copying / modifying each character you want to, and adding a space in the new string when needed

Let me know if it's not clear enough, or if you need more precise informations.

Comment: I need more precise information, where else can I reach you?

Comment: About which part? I can edit the answer to help you more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use magic numbers. Use standard functions instead.
2. passed string has to be modifiable and has enough room to accommodate new spaces.

The function below adds space after characters listed in the `after` string. If there is a blank space after this character it does not and skips all the blank spaces, then capitalize the first non-blank character. It does not add space if the character listed in `after` is the last in the string.

```
char *addSpaceAndCapitalizeAfter(char *str, const char *after)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    if(str && after)
    {
        while(*str)
        {
            if(strchr(after, *str))
            {
                if(str[1] && !isblank((unsigned char)str[1]) && str[2])
                {
                    memmove(str + 2, str + 1, strlen(str) + 1);
                    str[1] = ' ';
                    str++;
                }
                str++;
                while(*str && isblank((unsigned char)*str)) str++;
                if(*str) *str = toupper((unsigned char)*str);
            }
            else
            {
                str++;
            }
        }
    }
    return wrk;
}


int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = ",test,string,      some, words,";

    printf("`%s`\n", addSpaceAndCapitalizeAfter(str, ","));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ecq1zxqYW